# How can I print every line available from one BufferedReader before checking another BufferedReader?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

```
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(DoDSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(DoDSocket.getInputStream()));

        BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String fromServer;
        String fromUser;

        while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null)
        {

            System.out.println(fromServer);

            if ((fromUser= stdIn.readLine()) != null)
            {
                //System.out.println(fromUser);
                out.println(fromUser);
            }
        }
```

In this code for a client, I've created a Print Writer and a buffered reader which communicate with a Server, I also have a separate reader which reads the System.in from the command line.

My problem at the moment is that if the server send the client a multi line string, I will have to press enter to receive each line. How can I edit this code so that every line is printed from the buffered reader from the server, before it checks what the user has typed, rather than checking after every individual line?

Comment: You're going to need to separate the loop checking for messages from the server from the `if` statement checking for user input.

Comment: Could you be more specific? if I take the if statement out, the first loop never ends.

Comment: No it won't, it will end when `in.readLine()==null`

Comment: When I run this, it never comes out of the first loop as it isn't sending anything from the client side.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do one loop after the other?:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(DoDSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(DoDSocket.getInputStream()));
BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

String fromServer;
String fromUser;

while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null)
{
    System.out.println(fromServer);
}

while ((fromUser = stdIn.readLine()) != null)
{
    System.out.println(fromUser);
}
```

Comment: This prints everything from the server, but doesn't exit the first loop.

Comment: When would you like to exit the first loop - on what condition?

Or is it that you WANT to control it with user input, but you just want MORE input before printing it?

Comment: You can either print the lines from the server after a certain buffer size, a certain number of lines or when certain content is present in the stream.  Or, I guess, even after a certain amount of time has passed.

Comment: Essentially, I want the code to take turns checking for stuff from the server reader and then the user reader. But sometimes the server reader will send more than one line, which I want to have ALL printed before it checks the user reader again.

Comment: So what does ALL mean?  Imagine someone is sending you mail, in your mailbox.  They might send you more than one letter, they might not.  You want to reply only when they've finished each batch - how do you know when they've finished?  You need some indication - maybe sending a 'special message', reserve a special character or command that indicates the end of a batch, etc.

Comment: The sending a special character when finished a batch is a good idea, thankyou.